# PLCrashReporter - Symbolication issue

Tags: ios, plcrashreporter

I'm new to PLCrashReporter. I have a question regarding symbolication of crash data. I use PLCrashReporter API to read crash data and send it to a server. After that point, i use symbolicate crash script to symbolicate the crash report.

The problem is; I have ~10 projects in my workspace. When I generate my app which is shell.app , build process also generates the shell.app.dSYM file. Therefore, I use this .dSYM file to symbolicate in symbolicate script. However, it only symbolicates the hex codes that belong to shell project. See example below.

```
Thread 3 name:  Exception Backtrace
Thread 3:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x021c0022 0x20c2000 + 1040418
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00b11cd6 0xb0c000 + 23766
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02168a48 0x20c2000 + 682568
3   CoreFoundation                      0x021689b9 0x20c2000 + 682425
4   shell                               0x0004bd78 -[DocumentHubApplicationBarContentView applicationBarButtonTapped:] (DocumentHubApplicationBarContentView.mm:85)
5   shell                               0x00010657 -[ApplicationBarButton buttonTapped] (ApplicationBarButton.mm:48)
6   CoreFoundation                      0x021c1e99 0x20c2000 + 1048217
7   UIKit                               0x0109214e 0x1084000 + 57678
8   UIKit                               0x010920e6 0x1084000 + 57574
9   UIKit                               0x01138ade 0x1084000 + 740062
10  UIKit                               0x01138fa7 0x1084000 + 741287
11  UIKit                               0x01138266 0x1084000 + 737894
12  UIKit                               0x010b73c0 0x1084000 + 209856
13  UIKit                               0x010b75e6 0x1084000 + 210406
14  UIKit                               0x0109ddc4 0x1084000 + 105924
15  UIKit                               0x01091634 0x1084000 + 54836
16  GraphicsServices                    0x026b2ef5 0x26ab000 + 32501
17  CoreFoundation                      0x02194195 0x20c2000 + 860565
18  CoreFoundation                      0x020f8ff2 0x20c2000 + 225266
19  CoreFoundation                      0x020f78da 0x20c2000 + 219354
20  CoreFoundation                      0x020f6d84 0x20c2000 + 216452
21  CoreFoundation                      0x020f6c9b 0x20c2000 + 216219
22  GraphicsServices                    0x026b17d8 0x26ab000 + 26584
23  GraphicsServices                    0x026b188a 0x26ab000 + 26762
24  UIKit                               0x0108f626 0x1084000 + 46630
25  shell                               0x0000347d main (main.mm:42)
26  shell                               0x00002425 start + 53
27  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 0
```

Also, I checked the crash report that is also generated by iOS and it's fully symbolicated. Also, that crash report has more information that PLCrashReporter provides. Can someone enlighten me about this? Am I missing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To symbolicate the iOS system framework calls, you need to have the symbols of the corresponding iOS version existing on your system and available for the symbolication script.

Regarding your question `that crash report has more information that PLCrashReporter provides`: Without further specifying what exactly you are referring to, this cannot be answered.